# Adding plugin editing capability for Author

Tags: plugins, user-roles, author, capabilities

I am new to php environment. Any idea how we could enable plugin editing roles and capabilities for Author or another scenario could be adding as sub-admin with limited roles. Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Documentation for roles and capabilities here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/roles-and-capabilities/ It’s. If possible to provide anything more helpful because you haven’t described anything about what access you actually need to control.

Comment: Hey Jacob, Sorry for the late reply. I found a way after a lot of RnD. Thanks :)